# Asp.Net Web Api multiple files with additional data for each

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am trying to send multiple files along with some data for every file. This is my model:

```
public class FileDTO
{
    [Required]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost("Upload/{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int id, IEnumerable<FileDTO> appFileDTOs)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this even a correct way to do so? How do I send such a request in Postman to simulate it?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I tried it like this in Postman:

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Everything submits correctly besides the image. For some reason the image is always null...

Comment: When you it your controller, what is the value of 'var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` represents collection/dictionary index while dot(`.`) represents there's a property.

So you should rename all the field names with the dot representation.

For example,  change

```
appFileDTOs[0][File]
```

to

```
appFileDTOs[0].File
```

### Demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Would be good if there would be a better GUI from Postman for that kind of scenario. The way you have to send the data seems a little bit like a hack to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you,

send from formData.

in model key send value as

```
[
{
"CategoryName":"Category1",
"CategoryDescription ":"Category1 Description",
"Detail":"Details "
},
{
"CategoryName":"Category2",
"CategoryDescription ":"Category2 Description",
"Detail":"Details2"
}

]
```

and for file send first file as file1 and second file as file2;
[image]

In server side , remove IEnumerable of FileDTO appFileDTOs from method name.
get value of model as

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FileDTO>>(Request.Form["model"]);
```

simillary for file

```
   var fileUpload1 = Request.Form.Files["file1"];
   var fileUpload2 = Request.Form.Files["file2"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later!